# Autocomplete/intellisense OpenLayers in Visual Studio

Tags: openlayers, visual-studio-code

How can I enable autocomplete in Visual Studio Code when using OpenLayers?

Answer (score 1):

You can get OpenLayer via npm, them `import` it in your JS/TS code and inellisense should work immediately.

Create a new project (web app)

In solution explorer, right click, add item. Select `npm configuration file` which will create `package.json`

Edit package.json and add a dev dependency

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "oltest",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "ol": "6.1.1"
  }
}
```

Edit your JS file: add `import {Map} from 'ol';` and start using it. Intellisense will kick-in

You might have to right click on `dependencies \ npm` and choose `restore packages`

[image]